# Get SHA1 value for a folder containing one file

Tags: c#

I'm using a lightly modified version of [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9560/Get-MD-and-SHA-SHA-of-any-file) code to retrieve SHA1 values for specific files. It's working great. But I also need to be able to retrieve the SHA1 value for a folder containing one file and his code throws an error when I point it at a folder instead of a file.

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Users\MyUserName\Documents\Verify_List\ABC123' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at NightSHACompareTool.Main.butCrawlHash_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

The folder will contain a different file every time I scan it, but there will only ever be one file at a time in the folder. I don't care what the SHA1 value is for the underlying file; I need the SHA1 value for the folder containing the underlying file.

Comment: What do you want to happen when you (try to) open a folder with a filestream?

Comment: `I don't care what the SHA1 value is for the underlying file; I need the SHA1 value for the folder containing the underlying file.` what is the SHA1 of a folder? How is it computed?

Comment: How would the hash for a folder containing one file be different from the hash of that one file?  At long last, please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: The exception is trying to tell you, imperfectly, is that you can't open a directory as though it is a file.  You have to enumerate the files in the directory, one by one.  Directory.EnumerateFiles() or Directory.GetFiles() method.  How you combine the hashes for each file, or what you do when you discover that there is more than one file in the directory, is entirely up to you.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to convert the contents of the file in the desired folder to a string, and use a method on the string to get the desired SHA1 value.

For example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //test out random string
    string input = "im the contents of a file";
    //convert input string to Sha1
    string result = ConvertToSha1(input);

    Console.WriteLine(input);
    Console.WriteLine(result);


    Console.WriteLine("------------");

    //test out longer string

    input = "im the contents of a file asdkjaskldjaskljdaskljdklasjdklasjdklasjdklasjdklasjdklasjdklajsdklajskldjaskldjaskldjaskldjaskljdaklsjdaklsjdklasjdkl";

    result = ConvertToSha1(input);

    Console.WriteLine(input);
    Console.WriteLine(result);

    Console.WriteLine("------------"); ;

    //test out file string

    //This will search the bin folder for a text file named this
    string path = "../SomeRandomTextFile.txt";

    //store the file into a string
    string readText = File.ReadAllText(path);
    Console.WriteLine(readText);

    //convert to sha1
    result = ConvertToSha1(readText);
    Console.WriteLine("\n\n Converted to Sha1 \n\n {0}", result);

    Console.ReadLine();
}


public static string ConvertToSha1(string input)
{
    SHA1 sha = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();

    byte[] bytes = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));

    string result = BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", "");
    return result;
}
```

In the example the method created named `ConvertToSha1` will convert a string into a sha1 value.  It displays 2 tests that are seperated that you you can change the `input` and check the `result` using http://www.sha1-online.com/.  Lastly I create a `string`, `string readText = File.ReadAllText(path);` that contains the information in the `bin` folder located within the Program's namespace folder.  If you want you can change the path to be a concatenated string.

Hopefully this is what you were looking for.